# Does SQLite have performance shortage on recursive CTE or I write the sql wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

There's a tutorial：https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hierarchies-on-steroids-1-convert-an-adjacency-list-to-nested-sets

```
        USE TempDB;
--===== Conditionally drop Temp tables to make reruns easy
     IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Hierarchy','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE dbo.Hierarchy;
--===== Build the new table on-the-fly including some place holders
   WITH cteBuildPath AS 
( --=== This is the "anchor" part of the recursive CTE.
     -- The only thing it does is load the Root Node.
 SELECT anchor.EmployeeID, 
        anchor.ManagerID, 
        HLevel   = 1,
        SortPath =  CAST(
                        CAST(anchor.EmployeeID AS BINARY(4)) 
                    AS VARBINARY(4000)) --Up to 1000 levels deep.
   FROM dbo.Employee AS anchor
  WHERE ManagerID IS NULL --Only the Root Node has a NULL ManagerID
  UNION ALL 
 --==== This is the "recursive" part of the CTE that adds 1 for each level
     -- and concatenates each level of EmployeeID's to the SortPath column.  
 SELECT recur.EmployeeID, 
        recur.ManagerID, 
        HLevel   =  cte.HLevel + 1,
        SortPath =  CAST( --This does the concatenation to build SortPath
                        cte.SortPath + CAST(Recur.EmployeeID AS BINARY(4))
                    AS VARBINARY(4000))
   FROM dbo.Employee      AS recur
  INNER JOIN cteBuildPath AS cte 
          ON cte.EmployeeID = recur.ManagerID
) --=== This final SELECT/INTO creates the Node # in the same order as a
     -- push-stack would. It also creates the final table with some
     -- "reserved" columns on the fly. We'll leave the SortPath column in
     -- place because we're still going to need it later.
     -- The ISNULLs make NOT NULL columns.
 SELECT EmployeeID = ISNULL(sorted.EmployeeID,0),
        sorted.ManagerID,
        HLevel     = ISNULL(sorted.HLevel,0),
        LeftBower  = ISNULL(CAST(0 AS INT),0), --Place holder
        RightBower = ISNULL(CAST(0 AS INT),0), --Place holder
        NodeNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sorted.SortPath),
        NodeCount  = ISNULL(CAST(0 AS INT),0), --Place holder
        SortPath   = ISNULL(sorted.SortPath,sorted.SortPath)
   INTO dbo.Hierarchy
   FROM cteBuildPath AS sorted
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100) --Change this IF necessary
;
--===========================================================================
--      5.  Once the data from Steps 1, 2, 3, AND 4 is complete, update that
--          data with the calculated Left Bower.
--===========================================================================
--===== Calculate the Left Bower
 UPDATE dbo.Hierarchy
    SET LeftBower = 2 * NodeNumber - HLevel
;
--SELECT * FROM dbo.Hierarchy
```

I rewrite it to SQLite version:

```
 CREATE TABLE newtable AS  
    WITH recursive cteBuildPath(id, parent, HLevel, SortPath) AS 
( --=== This is the "anchor" part of the recursive CTE.
     -- The only thing it does is load the Root Node.
 SELECT anchor.id, 
        anchor.parent, 
        1 as HLevel,
        printf('%08d', anchor.id) as SortPath --Up to 1000 levels deep.
   FROM main AS anchor
  WHERE anchor.parent IS NULL --Only the Root Node has a NULL ManagerID
  UNION ALL 
 --==== This is the "recursive" part of the CTE that adds 1 for each level
     -- and concatenates each level of EmployeeID's to the SortPath column.  
 SELECT recur.id, 
        recur.parent, 
        cte.HLevel + 1 as HLevel,
        cte.SortPath || printf('%08d', Recur.id) as SortPath
   FROM main      AS recur
  INNER JOIN cteBuildPath AS cte 
          ON cte.id = recur.parent
) --=== This final SELECT/INTO creates the Node # in the same order as a
     -- push-stack would. It also creates the final table with some
     -- "reserved" columns on the fly. We'll leave the SortPath column in
     -- place because we're still going to need it later.
     -- The ISNULLs make NOT NULL columns.

 SELECT ifnull(sorted.id,0) as id,
        sorted.parent,
        ifnull(sorted.HLevel,0) as HLevel,
        ifnull(CAST(0 AS INT),0) as LeftBower, --Place holder
        ifnull(CAST(0 AS INT),0) as RightBower, --Place holder
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sorted.SortPath) as NodeNumber,
        ifnull(CAST(0 AS INT),0) as NodeCount, --Place holder
        ifnull(sorted.SortPath,sorted.SortPath) as SortPath
   FROM cteBuildPath AS sorted;
   
UPDATE newtable
SET LeftBower = 2 * NodeNumber - HLevel
```

As the tutorial said, 100 thousands node only need few seconds, but when I run the test, 1800 nodes needs 18seconds, and 160,000 nodes is not completed over 5 minutes, the sqlite expert professional freezes and I don't know if it is still running or not.
Obviously, this is not even close to the claimed performance!

I would like to know if it is impossible to optimize because SQLite is borned to be so slow in recursive calculation or just I wrote it wrong.
any information would be appreciated because I am new to SQL and database.

Comment: Do you have an index on `main.parent`?

Comment: Some reading: https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html https://sqlite.org/eqp.html https://sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_

Comment: And all but the first two `ifnull()`s are pointless, btw. `ifnull(x,x)` can be replaced by `x`. Especially when `x` is a constant non-null value like 0.

Comment: That is exactly because of the index. It is like miracle. I thought the index would be automatically generated... @Shawn

Comment: @Shawn and why would he use ifnull(x,x)? I don't see any necessarity to do so